# Bypass Chrome Android: LITE MODE (lazy loading) - force eager loading to full website

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-chrome, chrome-datasaver

**Hi**

**I have a website made in Bootstrap4.** Works fine until I detected an error specific to **Google Android Chrome browser** - and his default **LITE MODE.**

*If Im correct Lite Mode = Lazy loading, loads elements when needed (detected by scroll distance I suppose).*

**But I have an issue with this.** This is a onepager - a long website with menu on top. And Im not able to "scroll to ID" from top. Well I can, but I always end up on a imperfect scroll result. If I would call the scroll function again - it would now go *"exactly where supposed to".*

**So I suppose:** since lazy loading is on, some elements are not rendered and so the "scroll offsets" of JQuery are broken... The lower I scroll the "exacter" the "scroll to ID" function becomes.

But for users that do not scroll at all but want to click on the menu and scroll down - well they have a problem if they are on android chrome with lite mode on.

**Is there any way on to tell the browser "dont do lazy load here" please?**

**EDIT:**
**The project is online, if you wish to RECREATE IT follow these steps:**
*(Android device with Chrome needed)*

0. Have LITE version turned ON.
1. Open new TAB (this is important)
2. Visit: https://objednavka.pollitocheesecake.sk/
3. Scroll slowly to the first product you will see and push the green +
4. Now a new button "POKRACOVAT POPS UP"
5. Click on that and you will be send down and end on a "screen between" sections

If you do the same with LITE MODE OFF - you will end up on the next section withou any issues.

**Note:** Thew part with NEW TAB is important, on a simple reaload the lite version already renders the page and navigation works even on LITE MODE. Its first visits only.

**Thank you
Oliver**

Comment: Any chance a  CSS change could help?  How are you testing or debugging this?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS: I wrote a small function that outputs the distance (pixels from top of the 'to scroll div') when Im on very top, the distance is around 4800px (incorrectly, correct value is at 5200) and the lower I scroll, the closer the distance comes to 5200. Honestly you dont need to scroll much far, but if you dont scroll at all and just use the menu, you end up exactly these 400 pixels apart. Of course on disabled lite mode - problem dissapears.

Comment: I'm having problems with a dynamic website and lite mode / data saver as well, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, sadly no, I was not able to solve it. I bypassed my issue (length of the page before images load with scroll was incorrect) by creating DIV image holders with sizes intended for the image. With this - the page always has the correct length (height) calculated even with not loaded images.